# importing angular2/http in ionic 2 has error "cannot find module"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm started learning ionic 2 and I have a problem with importing dependency in my app.ts file.

when i want use:

```
"import {Http} from "angular2/http";
```

its show me, error with this subject:

```
[ts] cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
```

this is my package.json's content:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.7",
"ionic-native": "^1.1.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

ok, i found a solution,

in Ionic 2, Beta 7, we should use:

> import {Http} from '@angular/http';

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if this could be useful to someone, there are some other changes you would need to do in order to upgrade to **Ionic 2 beta 7** (or beta 8 now).

You can take a look at the recommended steps (and *breaking changes* like that one) [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta7-2016-05-19).

=========

**EDIT:**

As *Bond - Java Bond* suggests, these are the breaking changes in case of the link goes dead:

**2.0.0-beta.7 (2016-05-19) BREAKING CHANGES**

*Angular Update to 2.0.0-rc.1*

Angular has been updated to 2.0.0-rc.1, follow these steps to update Angular.

1. Edit your `package.json` and remove the `angular2` entry:

   ```
   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15"
   ```
2. Then, run the following command from a terminal to update Ionic and Angular, or take a look at the starter's package.json changes and update each version:

   ```
   npm install --save ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.7 @angular/core @angular/compiler @angular/common @angular/platform-browser @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @angular/router @angular/http rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 zone.js@0.6.12 reflect-metadata
   ```
3. Run the following command from a terminal to update the gulp task for `ionic-gulp-scripts-copy`:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev ionic-gulp-scripts-copy@2.0.0
   ```
4. Then, change any imports in your application from `angular2` to `@angular`. For example, the following.

   ```
   import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
   import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
   import {Http} from '@angular/http';
   ```
5. Remove the import for `angular2-polyfills` in `index.html`:

   ```
   <script src="build/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
   ```

   and replace it with the following scripts:

   ```
   <script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
   <script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
   ```
6. Replace all template variables in `ngFor` with `let`. For example:

   ```
   *ngFor="#session of group.sessions"
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   *ngFor="let session of group.sessions"
   ```
7. Replace all template variables in `virtualScroll`. For example:

   ```
   *virtualItem="#item"
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   *virtualItem="let item"
   ```
8. View the [Angular Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more in depth changes.

Comment: Although this might answer the question, do consider summarizing the link content for benefit of future readers in case the link goes dead.